# EaselJS and SpriteSheet

Tags: sprite-sheet, easeljs

I'm simply trying to get each frame in a sprite sheet but all I keep getting is the first frame, here's the code:

```
function handleImageLoaded(e)
{
    var c   = new Container();
    var d   = { };
    var l   = rx * ry;
    var lh  = canvas.height / ry;
    var lw  = canvas.width / rx;
    var lx  = 0;
    var ly  = 0;
    var s;
    var t;

    d.images    = [ e.target ];
    d.frames    = { width: lw, height: lh, count: l };

    s   = new SpriteSheet( d );

    for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++ )
    {
        t   = new Bitmap( s.getFrame( i ).image );

        t.x = lx++ * lw;
        t.y = ( lx == rx ? ly++ : ly ) * lh;

        lx  = lx == rx ? 0 : lx;

        c.addChild( t );
    }

    stage.addChild( c );

    stage.update();
}
```

I would stick this up on a fiddle but there'd be cross domain issues with the image.

Answer (score 1):

try `SpriteSheetUtils.exractFrame` (see [SpriteSheetUtils](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/src/easeljs/utils/SpriteSheetUtils.js)). It does exactly what you do in your custom code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is that the frame.image property points to the source bitmap, which is the same for all frames in the spritesheet (unless you have a multi-image spritesheet).

To display a frame from a spritesheet, use Sprite. For example, modifying your code:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++ )
{
    t   = new Sprite(spriteSheet, i);

    t.x = lx++ * lw;
    t.y = ( lx == rx ? ly++ : ly ) * lh;

    lx  = lx == rx ? 0 : lx;

    c.addChild( t );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, while I wasn't able to fix the problem with EaselJS, I just worked around it. I created a function that replicated the `getFrame` function that EaselJS's sprite stuff was meant to do, here it is:

```
function generateTile(p, i)
{
    var cs  = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    var c   = cs.getContext( '2d' );

    cs.height   = p[ 3 ];
    cs.width    = p[ 2 ];

    c.drawImage( i, p[ 0 ], p[ 1 ], p[ 2 ], p[ 3 ], 0, 0, p[ 2 ], p[ 3 ] );

    return new Bitmap( cs );
}
```